# Getting NaN from JavaScript function trying to get same data more than once

Tags: javascript, datetime, jtable

```
updateAction: function(postData) {
    console.log("updating from custom function...");
    return $.Deferred(function($dfd) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'HallManagementServlet?action=UpdateStudent',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: postData,
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(entryindex, entry) {
                    payment_date.push(entry['payment_expires_on']);  
                });
                var current_date = new Date();
                var current_date_in_millis = current_date.getMilliseconds();

                var last_payment_date = payment_date;
                alert(Date.parse(last_payment_date)+"Second 1"+Date.parse(current_date));
                $dfd.resolve(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                $dfd.reject();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I'm trying to parse two date here. But `last_payment_date` is giving me `NaN` if I try to get that value twice.

Why is it giving me `NaN` when I try to edit my `JTable` list more than once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the culprit is `payment_date` and `Date.parse()`

`Date.parse()` can handle an array of length 1

```
Date.parse(['01-01-2015']) // 1420088400000
```

> Why is it giving me NaN when I try to edit my JTable list more than once?

When you update the table the first time `payment_date` probably only has one entry, the second time it will likely have 2 or more entries.

```
Date.parse(['01-01-2015', '03-03-2015']) // NaN
```

Try this:

```
var data = ['10-03-2015', '01-01-2015', '03-03-2015'];
$.each(data, function(entryindex, entry) {
    payment_date.push(Date.parse(entry['payment_expires_on']));  
});

// ...

// Presumably the last payment date is chronologically the last one,
// but I am not sure if that is true or not.
payment_date.sort();

var last_payment_date = payment_date[payment_date.length - 1];
// last_payment_date is a now a timestamp, don't use Date.parse() on it.

// ...
```

Comment: You can sort your `payment_date` array and always use the greatest timestamp for `last_payment_date`. Presumably the last payment date is chronologically the last one, but I am not sure if that is true or not.

Comment: That didn't work for me. But i declared  last_payment_date variable inside success. So every time the method is running  last_payment_date will be updated with the new value.

Comment: @TanziraNajninTonu, I am glad you have it working now.

Answer (score 2):

`last_payment_date` is of type `Array`. You need to index it first:

```
Date.parse(last_payment_date[0])
```